# Pandas: Need a speedier way of index slicing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

Anyone care to take a stab at speeding up this dataframe index slicing scheme?
I'm trying to slice and dice some huge dataframes, so every bit counts. I need to somehow find a faster way of index slicing the dataframe, other than the following technique:

```
v = initFrame.xs(x,level=('ifoo2','ifoo3'), drop_level=False)
```

Also the loop in pd.unique is impacting performance pretty significantly.

```
uniqueList = list(pd.unique(initFrame[['bar1','bar4']].values))
```

Copy and paste the below snippet to avoid setup.

```
import pandas as pd

foo1 = (['LABEL1','LABEL1','LABEL2','LABEL2'])
foo2 = ([5,5,6,6])
foo3 = ([1,1,2,3])

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([foo1,foo2,foo3], names=['ifoo1','ifoo2','ifoo3'])

initFrame = pd.DataFrame({'bar1': [ 5,6,5,6],
                          'bar2': ['a','b','c','d'],
                          'bar3': [11,22,33,44],
                          'bar4': [1,2,1,3]}, index=index)
                           
finDict = {}
#start timer1
uniqueList = list(pd.unique(initFrame[['bar1','bar4']].values))
#end timer1
for x in uniqueList:
    #start timer2
    v = initFrame.xs(x,level=('ifoo2','ifoo3'), drop_level=False)
    #stop timer2
    k = int(x[0]), int(x[1])  
    finDict.update({k:v})
```

## UPDATE 2016-04-04

For those interested, I ended up using the following:

```
finDict = {}
grouper = initFrame.groupby(level=('ifoo2', 'ifoo3'))
for name, group in grouper:
    finDict.update({name:group})
```

Comment: are you concern about speed between 2 timers, or the loop in `uniqueList`?

Comment: Ah your right! Didn't complete my post. Edited now, thanks.

Comment: to perform a `unique` and `list`, then again a for loop is like doing 3 x loops against 1 possible loop. And again given that your dataset is huge, the prep is going to take forever to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension together with `loc` to do the dataframe indexing:

```
finDict = {pair: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, pair[0], pair[1]], :] 
           for pair in pd.unique(initFrame[['bar1', 'bar4']].values).tolist()}

>>> finDict
{(5, 1):                     bar1 bar2  bar3  bar4
 ifoo1  ifoo2 ifoo3                       
 LABEL1 5     1         5    a    11     1
              1         6    b    22     2,
 (6, 2):                     bar1 bar2  bar3  bar4
 ifoo1  ifoo2 ifoo3                       
 LABEL2 6     2         5    c    33     1,
 (6, 3):                     bar1 bar2  bar3  bar4
 ifoo1  ifoo2 ifoo3                       
 LABEL2 6     3         6    d    44     3}
```

Comment: nice comprehension

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you really want to do, but here is some hint to speedup your code:

change

```
uniqueList = list(pd.unique(initFrame[['bar1','bar4']].values))
```

to

```
uniqueList = initFrame[["bar1", "bar4"]].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
```

and the for loop to :

```
g = initFrame.groupby(level=(1, 2))
uniqueSet = set(uniqueList)
dict((key, df) for key, df in g if key in uniqueSet)
```

or:

```
g = initFrame.groupby(level=(1, 2))
dict((key, g.get_group(key)) for key in uniqueList)
```

Here is the %timeit compare:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (10000, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=("A", "B"))

%timeit df.drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
%timeit list(pd.unique(arr))
```

outputs:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 3.51 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 94.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: wouldn't the `drop_duplicates` is slower than `pd.unique`? I think we can just loop them once with `iterrows()` -- since multi-indexes are grouped, we can simply compare and skip the loop if value of ('bar1', 'bar4') equals to previous one, then perform the dict update.

Comment: @Anzel, I added a %timeit test, you can look at the result. It's 20x faster.

Comment: on mine: `%timeit initFrame[["bar1", "bar4"]].drop_duplicates().values.tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop`, 
`%timeit list(pd.unique(initFrame[['bar1','bar4']].values))
1000 loops, best of 3: 470 µs per loop`. But I guess yours could be performant if the dataset is large enough

Comment: I confirm `drop_duplicates` is indeed like 20x faster given the array is large. I have the similar output as yours. Apologise for my first ignorant comment :-)

Comment: @HYRY FYI. ``pd.unique`` is for pure dtypes, using tuples is effectively using ``object`` which much slower. Try with a single column and see the diff. ``.drop_duplicates()`` basically factorizes things, then calls ``.unique()``

Comment: Had to give the green check to @Alexander for his clean answer that others can just copy and paste for a quick solution, but BIG PROPS to @HYRY! I forgot all about df.groupby, that allowed me to refactor and drop the loops, for a big performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

Not as a answer but just to visualise a thought re my comment, since multi-indexes are grouped, we can simply & possibly just compare and skip the loop if value of *('bar1', 'bar4')* equals to the previous value, then perform the dict update.

It may not be speedier, but if your dataset is huge, it could potentially save you a memory consumption problem, pseudo code:

```
# ...replace timer1...
prev, finDict = None, {}
for n in initFrame[['bar1', 'bar4']].iterrows():
    current = (n[0][1], n[0][2])
    if current == prev: continue
    prev = current
    #... whatever faster way to solve your 2nd timer...
```

Personally I think @Alexander answers your 2nd timer rather nicely.